# Is it possible to extend eclipse's Project Reference page to add a new control like textbox or a dropdown?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm aware that we can add new pages to property dialog by adding org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages extension point, but in my case I want to use the existing eclipse's Project References page and add a dropdown in it. Can you please let me know if this can be acheieved? if yes, then how can it be done?

Expected Project Reference page modification:
[image: Expected Project Reference page modification]

Comment: No that isn't possible, Eclipse does not provide a way to modify that page (`org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.dialogs.ProjectReferencePage`)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found a workaround, it is as follows: 1. Add a new property page with same id as that of ProjectReferencePage. (this will override the original project reference page) 2. Copy the code from ProjectReferencePage and adapt it to our need. Is this approach recommended?

Comment: Why should your page override the original? I don't think there is any guarantee that will happen.

Comment: Because we do not wish to have two pages listing the referencable Projects.

Comment: No, what I mean is why would Eclipse use your replacement page with the same id. If Eclipse finds two pages with the same id there is no guarantee which one it will use.